# Pass list attribute from lightning component to apex controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an `attribute` in lightning component:

`<aura:attribute name="pricingRecommendationListDetailsData" access="PUBLIC" type="list" default="object[]" />`

Data stored in it visible as:

`{accRecmId: "a07e000", category: "test", Price: 56, PriceRange: {…}, cost: 0.3, …}`

Now I need to pass this attribute as parameter to apex controller on button click.And I need to iterate over values such as `accRecmId` in `apex class`

Comment: You would simply pass it using the method param name and the component.get of the attribute

Comment: But how will I iterate over the list<string> and grab `accRecmId` from each instance?

Comment: More of a map isn’t it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have two option:

1. Send only the accRecmId to your Server method like this:

JS Controller:

```
var selectedList = component.get('v.pricingRecommendationListDetailsData');

    var ids=new Array();
    for (var i= 0 ; i < selectedList.length ; i++){
        ids.push(selectedList[i].accRecmId);
    }

    var idListJSON=JSON.stringify(ids);

    var action = component.get("c.callServier");
    action.setParams({
            "accRecmId":idListJSON
    });
```

Apex Controller:

```
public static void callServier(String accRecmId) {
    Type idArrType = Type.forName('List<string>');
    List<string> wrapperList = (List<string>) JSON.deserialize(accRecmId, idArrType);
}
```

2. Pass all attribute to your apex controller and inside your apex controller get the accRecmId.

Comment: `var ids = selectedList.map(value => value.accRecmId);` There's usually a shorter way than a `for(...)` loop in modern JS.

Comment: Why not just pass the map to the apex method and do the work needed there? Provide much more flexibility to extend the functionality later on....Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to prepare the required data on the client and send only the list of ids you have to work within the server:

**MyComponentController.js**

```
// get the list of pricing details
var pricingDetails = component.get('v.pricingRecommendationListDetailsData');
// map through the list to create a list of acc rec ids
var accRecmIds = pricingDetails.map(function (detail) {
    return detail.accRecmId;
});

// get the server call action
var action = component.get("c.iterateOverAccRecmIds");
// set the list of acc rec ids as a parameter
action.setParams({
    "accRecmIds":accRecmIds
});
```

**MyComponentController.cls**

```
public with sharing class MyComponentController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void iterateOverAccRecmIds(List<String> accRecmIds) {
        // do what you want with the list of ids...
    }
}
```